# Force SQLAlchemy to Log to File Only

Tags: python, logging, sqlalchemy

I'm using Python (3.8) and SQLAlchemy (1.4.29) to work with an SQL database for a web application project. According to SQLAlchemy's [Engine Configuration](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html#dbengine-logging) docs, I can use Python's [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) module to control where and how the logs output.

I want the SQLAlchemy engine to output to a file (`logs/actions.log`), and stop the logger from outputting to `sys.stdout`, so I took this approach:

```py
import logging
import sqlalchemy as sq
from sqlalchemy import orm

logger = logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy')
handler = logging.FileHandler("logs/actions.log")

logger.handlers = []

handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(handler)

engine = sq.create_engine(DB_URI, echo=True)
session = (orm.sessionmaker(engine))()
```

But this will output in both the file and and `sys.stdout`. How can I prevent this? Thanks!

*Yes, I've seen similar questions, they didn't help solve my issue.*

Comment: Apart from logger configuration, set `echo=False` on the engine to suppress stdout output.

Comment: @snakecharmerb If I set `echo=False`, then nothing will be output at all. Not sure why that is.

Comment: @C.Nivs Adding a FileHandler to that results in the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `logger.propagate = False` - it may be that the events logged to the `sqlalchemy` logger are also passed to a `StreamHandler` attached to the root logger. You can print `logging.getLogger().handlers` to see if that is the case. If not, check if the last two lines add a handler that you're not aware of by printing `logger.handlers` after those two calls.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the *logger's* `setLevel` method such that the logger's level will permit messages of the level that you want the handler to handle.  The SQLAlchemy loggers have a level of WARNING by default, so if you want the handler to handle debug messages then the logger must too.

This example demonstrates configuring the "sqlalchemy.engine" logger.

```py
import logging

import sqlalchemy as sa

logfile = 'actions.log'

logging.basicConfig()
logger = logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy')
logger.propagate = False
# Ensure logfile is truncated for demonstration
handler = logging.FileHandler(logfile, mode='w')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

logger.handlers = []

handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(handler)

# Suppress output from child loggers
logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine').handlers = []
logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.pool').handlers = []

engine = sa.create_engine('sqlite://', echo=False, echo_pool=False)
with engine.connect() as conn:
    conn.execute(sa.text('select 1 = 2'))

with open(logfile) as f:
    print(f.read())
```

output

```
Created new connection <sqlite3.Connection object at 0x7fbadd93ef40>
Connection <sqlite3.Connection object at 0x7fbadd93ef40> checked out from pool
select 1 = 2
[generated in 0.00022s] ()
Col ('1 = 2',)
Connection <sqlite3.Connection object at 0x7fbadd93ef40> being returned to pool
Connection <sqlite3.Connection object at 0x7fbadd93ef40> rollback-on-return
```